# How to program dynamic preview on site

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I'm asking for some orientation and recommendations for developing something similar like the yahoo movies page: http://movies.yahoo.com/

I don't know how the thing at the top with the arrows and different title of movies is called but I've seen it several times.(the one that has 4 options:expendables, yogi bear, etc) I want to add something like this so I'm asking for orientation on what to look for and develop it on java script.

thanks!

Comment: view the source of that url, could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's what's called a Carousel, and there are many libraries and plugins for doing it. You might try Yahoo's own [YUI Carousel Control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/carousel/) or [this one](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) for jQuery, but there are plenty of others out there--just [Google for them](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+carousel).

Answer (score 0):

It's basically four links and four images here. When you click on the link, the associated image will be shown.

I will show you an example.

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
    <a class="link-first" href="#">Show image 1</a> 
    <a class="link-second" href="#">Show image 2</a>
</div>

<div class="images">
    <img class="image-first" href="#" alt="" /> 
    <img class="image-second" href="#" alt="" />
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(".links a").click(function()
{
    $(".images img").hide();
    $(".images ." + this.className.split("-")[1]).show();
});
```